# Qt connecting signals and slots

Tags: qt4, signals, slots, disabled-control, disabled-input

In my Qt project I've a `QPushButton` and a `QLineEdit` instances. And I want to set QLineEdit disabled when QPushButton is pressed.

I've written this code:

```
this->btn = new QPushButton(this);
this->txt = new QLineEdit(this);
QObject::connect(this->btn,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this->txt,SLOT(setDisabled(bool)));
```

which doesn't work. 
Can you help me please? What is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `clicked(bool)` signal is always `false` for non-checkable buttons. It will never emit `true` unless you set `setCheckable(true)`, in which case it emits `true` when you check it, and `false` when you uncheck it. Non-checkable buttons cannot be checked (obviously), which is why the signal always emits `false`.

So in this case, simply provide your own slot where you manually toggle between `setDisabled(true)` and `setDisabled(false)`. Or make the button checkable first with `setCheckable(true)` (it might even be more suitable in this case; just test it and see.)

Answer (score 0):

`QLineEdit` does not have a method `setDisabled` according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlineedit.html#public-functions)

Try `setReadOnly` instead.

Comment: The documentation says that it has `19 public slots inherited from QWidget`, and `void  setDisabled ( bool disable )` in particular.

Comment: Sry, you are right. Is the button checkable? Otherwise the argument seems to be false all the time.

Comment: Nope, the button is not checkable... Seems like I should implement my own signal?

Comment: Or you could extend `QLineEdit` and implement a `toggleDisabled()` that does not need any arguments.